# sails js passport serializeUser field

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm making an sails js app that authenticates users with `passport` for  authentication 
and i need to  change serialize field instead of 'id' to 'userid'
 my model.js :

```
 id: {
  type: 'integer',
  required: false,
  size: 56,
  autoIncrement: true
}
```

and config.js:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
done(null, user.userid); 
 });
```

i have an error which 
 `console.log(err)`

```
[Error: Failed to serialize user into session]
```